# Replacing single and double quotes in MySQL - resulting in all fields showing 'BEST'?

Tags: mysql, sql

Right so I'm trying to replace all occurrences of double quotes in a MySQL database using:

```
UPDATE datatable SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, '"', '');
```

But it keeps replacing all fields in that column with the word BEST. Any clue why?

Comment: Not all the fields in the column contain double quotes, but every single field has changed to BEST

Comment: And what are you trying to replace them with? Your query *should* simply remove the double quotes.

Comment: Elliot - unless there's some monumental hard-drive failure, there's no way the query in your question could have replaced every column with `BEST`. If others are using the database I'd start checking with them.

Comment: Literally just me using it on a local machine.. Very odd! It's doing it on all tables..

Comment: Must be something else: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48651/1

Comment: My best guess (pun intended :-) ) would be that you've got some trojan/virus affecting your database.

Comment: I'm guessing it must be too now, at first I thought this might be a slightly uncommon issue that was something obvious!

Comment: Check if you have a trigger on your table.

Comment: By the way, what's the point in removing double quotes at all?

Comment: What's the actual name of the column ?

Comment: the actual name of the column is 'customer_address' - removing the double quotes because when I export the file to a csv it seems to mess up a bit

Comment: in CSV you can quote a quote simply by doubling it, just as `""`: `"Monitor 14"""` will represent `Monitor 14"` string

Answer (score 2):

This is a too localized question that lacks common sense.

A developer should always be a realistic man.

A common sense tells us that **no statement** like `REPLACE(column_name, '"', '')` can replace to the word "BEST".

So, such a question should never be asked but some investigation have to be done.
Apparently, **it is not the statement** posted here is responsible for the issue, but there is **some other code** that does update, or you are checking wrong database, running wrong script, etc. etc. All these guesses are *real* ones. While assumption that Mysql would replace a double quote wit the word "BEST" is not.

Yes, sometimes a terrible bug found in Mysql.  Yet, to prove such a case, just one alone statement out of nowhere by no means can be a proof. To make a proof, a realistic-looking question, one have to post

- table structure
- sample data dump
- replace query
- output of SELECT query run after replace

this way anyone be able to reproduce and confirm or disprove the statement

Comment: I do apologise.. I assumed it may be a common issue, or something obvious. It seems restarting the MySQL service has stopped this happening now, but the table structure was nothing different from a standard one (6 columns detailing customer contact details), the replace query is in the original question, and the SELECT query returns all but the column in question correctly, and the column in question just showing the word BEST in every row..

Comment: Also, there is as yet no other code - this happened in the MySQL cli. It's going into PHP though, which was why I mentioned it in case there was a more efficient way someone may know

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not replacing the field contents with the column name itself ?

The `mysqli` tag makes me think about PHP .. if `column_name` is a variable you may be actually doing this at runtime:

```
UPDATE datatable SET TheColumn = REPLACE('TheColumn', '"', '');
```

Which would produce the odd behavior you're experiencing. I honestly can't think of any other explanation for this behavior.

Comment: Especially if ' characters have been used around the column name as opposed to ` characters this might be hard to spot, but it definitely makes sense that this *could* be the possible "bug".

Comment: Just wiped a database because I didn't read properly. DO NOT ENTER QUOTES AROUND TheColumn :(

Comment: Lesson learned I hope.

Comment: multiple lessons. lesson 1: read. lesson 2: have a backup

Comment: 3. Don't update without a `WHERE`.